# Hibernate InheritanceType JOINED with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, inheritance

Lets say that I have two tables in my PostgreSQL database:

```
create table if not exists USM_USERS (
    USR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    USR_LOGIN VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT NN_USR_LOGIN NOT NULL
);

create table if not exists USM_PERSONS (
    PRS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    PRS_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT NN_PRS_FIRST_NAME NOT NULL,
    PRS_LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT NN_PRS_LAST_NAME NOT NULL,
    PRS_DOMAIN VARCHAR(1)
);

ALTER TABLE USM_USERS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PRS_USR_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (USR_ID) REFERENCES USM_PERSONS (PRS_ID);
```

and I want to map them to object-oriented model (using Java and Hibernate) as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "USM_PERSONS", schema = "public")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PRS_DOMAIN")
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class AbstractPersonData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRS_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PRS_FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "PRS_LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "USM_PERSONS", schema = "public")
public class PersonData extends AbstractPersonData {

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "USM_USERS", schema = "public")
@DiscriminatorValue("U")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "USR_ID")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserData extends AbstractPersonData {

    @Column(name = "USR_ID")
    private Long usrId;

    @Column(name = "USR_LOGIN")
    private String login;

}
```

**Next I'm trying to get the data using EntityManager (entityManager.find(PersonData.class, id); entityManager.find(UserData.class, id);) for PersonData it works well but for UserData i'm getting error:**

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column userdata0_.prs_id does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "userdata0_.usr_id".
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
```

**The question is: Have I missed any annotation? or maybe do I need to reorganize the classes/tables?**

Comment: Can you share the problematic query?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `@MappedSuperclass` and try to add `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` in your abstract class.

Please refer to: [Mapping Java Entities for Persistence With Hibernate](https://dzone.com/articles/mapping-java-entities-for-persistence-with-hiberna-1)